# Linux unzip command fails to unzip file

Tags: linux, shell, jar, zip, unzip

I have a zip file named **test_kit.zip** which contains a shell script **deploy.sh** inside it. The shell script file has read, write and, execute permission.

I want to unzip this test_kit.zip file

1. Using **jar xf** or **7zip**

```
jar xf test_kit.zip
7za x test_kit.zip
```

These commands unzip the zip file correctly but, the deploy.sh shell script loses the execute permission. Is there any way to unzip using 'jar xf' or '7za x' without losing execute permission for the files and folders inside the zip file?

2. Using unzip

```
unzip test_kit.zip
```

This command gives me an error which is as follows-

```
warning [test_kit.zip]:  1318507533 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [test_kit.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

I want to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Was the zip file created on Linux as well?

Comment: @user1934428 No, It was created on Windows.

Comment: Then you can't expect the attributes to be carried over, in particular the execute permissions! The permission model differ too much.